# Volatile variables in Server EndPoint for WebSocket Java API?

Tags: java, multithreading, websocket, thread-safety, volatile

Looking at other examples across the web, when a server endpoint is created by means of Java API for WebSocket, the shared variables among all EndPoint instances are defined as static, but not volatile. I would like to know the reason.

As I understand, the clients opening websockets will create a new thread in the server. So to be thread-safe, shouldn't be defined as **volatile** the shared variables among EndPoint instances?

i.e. Instead of:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/endpoint")
public class WebsocketEndPoint {
   private static Set<WebsocketEndPoint> endPoint = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<WebsocketEndPoint> ();

   @OnOpen
   public void onOpen(Session session, String message) {
...
```

is not better this code?:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/endpoint")
public class WebsocketEndPoint {
   private static volatile Set<WebsocketEndPoint> endPoint = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<WebsocketEndPoint> ();

   @OnOpen
   public void onOpen(Session session, String message) {
...
```

Comment: While this cannot be inferred from the code snippets above with absolute certainty, it seems like the `endPoint` field is effectively final, i.e. you could rewrite its definition as `private static final Set<WebsocketEndPoint> endPoint = ...`. Since `CopyOnWriteArraySet` is thread-safe itself, it makes the whole construction thread-safe and volatile is not necessary.

Comment: So it means that in the case of another variable type (different than CopyOnWriteArraySet) being non thread-safe, we should use volatile? Is that right?

Comment: I'd rather point to the "effectively final" part as a reason why volatile doesn't really apply in this case. Volatile guarantees happens-before relations between reads and writes to a reference. If there are no writes, this isn't really useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `volatile` keyword in cases in which a variable is modified by some thread, but may be read by a different one (and there aren't any other synchronization mechanisms in place).

So the question is whether there is a scenario in which some thread changes the `Set` to a different one, and a second thread tries to access it. For example, if some thread does this: `endPoint = new HashSet<>()`, while a different thread does this: `endPoint.get(...)`, then yes, the `Set` should be `volatile`.

However if the different threads use the same `Set` instance, then the `endPoint` reference doesn't change, and is "effectively final". In that case, there's no need to add the `volatile` keyword.

So the short answer is "it depends", since we need to look at complete example to see whether the `Set` should be volatile. I do want to point out one thing though - the use of an `CopyOnWriteArraySet` seems a bit odd since modifications to the set would only create a modified **copy** in the context of the modifying thread (that's what copy-on-write means).